# Changing ListView rightclick to check to hold instead

Tags: listview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, right-click

I've managed this long to not ask a question because Google/Stackoverflow has given me an answer, but I'm royally stuffed now.

Developing an app for Metro/WinRT/Windows 8 Tablet and managed to get it to work as it should.

Only problem is, to select an item in the ListView, you have to right click.  Right tap isn't working but I think I'm being silly.

Want to have it so when the user "holds" an item (or even just taps), it'll select, but can't find how the little checkbox appears when the user rightclicks.

Searched through the whole solution for Right, in an attempt to find the righttap/click command, but can't find anything..

Once I've done that, I need to be able to only select one item in each "group", but that's another problem for another day.

Still really new to this, but been programming VB 6/.NET for a few years, on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 points to answer

1 - Right Tap : It is just hold the tile and drag down it will get selected.

2 - Single Select : For single selection go through this link

[Selection Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode)

this will help u I guess . :)

Also take a look at the touch interacions. Will help later :)

Comment: Actually for a ListView it's Drag to the side not Drag down.

Comment: Same Means u have to drag since no right click :) Forgot the direction. But the start menu in a Surface Tab gives us a drag down option also . Dunno .

Comment: The start menu is a GridView, that why it's a Drag down. A listView has a vertical scroll by default that why it's a drag to the side (otherwise the item will just scroll when you try to drag it) but I agree it's just a detail :)

Comment: Thanks :) Common Sense just forgot :)